# Which matrix norm is used here and why is the rate of convergence linear?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am reading the paper "Centroidal Voronoi Tessellations: Applications and Algorithms" by Qiang Du, and I have questions about the following.

[image]

Here, Du talks about fixed point iteration of Lloyd and I am wondering where he gets
$||\tilde T||=cos^2(\pi/2(k+1))$. Which norm is he using?

Also, why does $1-||T|| \approx (\pi^2/4k^2)$ show that the Lloyd's method converges linearly?

Answer (score 0):

I think they must be using the norm induced by $\ell^2$.  To compute this, you need to compute the singular values of the matrices $\tilde T_k$.  If you can show the matrices are symmetric and positive semi-definite, this is equivalent to finding the eigenvalues.  Since $\tilde T_k$ is symmetric, you only need to show all the eigenvalues are non-negative.  You can compute the eigenvalues using, for example, equation (4) from this paper: http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf (which I found using google).

If you know that $\|T_k\| < 1$, then you know that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \|\vec e^{n+1}\|_2/\|\vec e^n\|_2 \le \|T_k\| < 1$, that is, you have linear order of convergence.

Comment: If $1-\|T\|$ is a small positive number, then $\|T\|$ must be strictly less than 1.  The size of $1-\|T\|$ also gives a good indication of how fast the convergence will be.

Comment: Because if $1 - \|T\| = \epsilon$, then $\|T\| = 1-\epsilon$, and so after $n$ iterations the error will be multiplied by $(1-\epsilon)^n \approx e^{-\epsilon n} \approx  1 - n \epsilon$, where the last approximation is reasonable if $n$ is smaller than $1/\epsilon$.